# Split a string using regex and include pattern

Tags: python, regex

I need to split a string on the degree (MSC, BSc,...) and keep the name with the title in column 0 and the address in column 1. **Note the country code at the end `BS` matches the title**

Please find some sample data below:

```
Phillipp Shuster MSc Grolmanstraße 6 28195 Bremen Bahnhofsvorstadt DE
Eric Jager BSc Mohrenstrasse 29 72362 Nusplingen DE
Nykee Peters BS Taylor Street, Duncan Town BS
```

I want to finish as below:

```
Phillipp Shuster MSc    |   Grolmanstraße 6 28195 Bremen Bahnhofsvorstadt DE
Eric Jager BSc          |   Mohrenstrasse 29 72362 Nusplingen DE
Nykee Peters BS         |   Taylor Street, Duncan Town BS
```

I tried this, but this adds the title to the address (**Not correct**).

```
splitted=re.split("\s(?=(?:msc|bsc|bs)[^$])",participants, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

Phillipp Shuster    | Msc Grolmanstraße 6 28195 Bremen Bahnhofsvorstadt DE
Eric Jager          | BSc   Mohrenstrasse 29 72362 Nusplingen DE
Nykee Peters        | BS Taylor Street, Duncan Town BS
```

Comment: @Code Maniac: I tried a lookbehind but received an error `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`. "\s(?<=(?:msc|bsc|bs)[^$])

Comment: Try `re.split(r'(?i)(?:(?<=\b[mb]sc)|(?<=\bbs))\s+', s)`

Comment: One could deal with the lookbehind fixed length issue by putting a single space before `bs` like so: `splitted=re.split("\s(?=(?:msc|bsc| bs)[^$])",participants, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`.

Comment: @Red Cricket: Can you explain me why this works? What's the 'space trick' doing? BTW it should be: `splitted=re.split("\s(?<=(?:msc|bsc| bs)[^$])",participants, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: @JohnDoe Please take a look at https://regex101.com/r/4iUB1H/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this mate**

```
(?<=\bmsc)|(?<=\bbsc)|(?<=\bbs)\s
```

- `(?<=\bmsc)` - Matches `msc`.
- `(?<=\bbsc)` - Matches `bsc`.
- `(?<=\bbs)` - Matches `bs`.
- `\s` - Matches space.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T1uHoe/2)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting I would suggest **`re.subn`** approach:

```
import re

data = '''Phillipp Shuster MSc Grolmanstraße 6 28195 Bremen Bahnhofsvorstadt DE
Eric Jager BSc Mohrenstrasse 29 72362 Nusplingen DE
Nykee Peters BS Taylor Street, Duncan Town BS'''

pattern = re.compile(r'^.+? (msc|bsc|bs)', flags=re.I)

for line in data.split('\n'):
    result = pattern.subn(lambda m: '{:<20s} | '.format(m.group()), line, count=1)
    print(result[0])
```

The output:

```
Phillipp Shuster MSc |  Grolmanstraße 6 28195 Bremen Bahnhofsvorstadt DE
Eric Jager BSc       |  Mohrenstrasse 29 72362 Nusplingen DE
Nykee Peters BS      |  Taylor Street, Duncan Town BS
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `split` you can use this simple regex with 2 captured group in `findall`:

```
reg = r'(?i)^(.*\s[BM]Sc?)\s+(.+)$'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lz7JPc/1)

**RegEx Description:**

- `(?i)`: Ignore case mode
- `^`: start
- `(.*\s[BM]Sc?)`: Match 0+ characters till `BSc` or `BS` or `MS` or `Msc` in capture group 1
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(.+)`: Match 1+ characters until end in 2nd capture group
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

My *2c* using `re.sub`:

```
import re
x = """Phillipp Shuster MSc Grolmanstraße 6 28195 Bremen Bahnhofsvorstadt DE
Eric Jager BSc Mohrenstrasse 29 72362 Nusplingen DE
Nykee Peters BS Taylor Street, Duncan Town BS"""

for y in x.split("\n"):
    print(re.sub("^(.*?(?:MS|BS)c?)(.*)", r"\1 |\2", y, 0, re.DOTALL))
```

---

**Output:**

```
Phillipp Shuster MSc | Grolmanstraße 6 28195 Bremen Bahnhofsvorstadt DE
Eric Jager BSc | Mohrenstrasse 29 72362 Nusplingen DE
Nykee Peters BS | Taylor Street, Duncan Town BS
```

---

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/R7o)
[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L7IxqN/1)